# Write keywords to files using a table of filenames and keywords

Tags: import-from-excel

I conduct research on rainforest cats in Africa. I have been using exiftool to extract keywords from photos to create tables that I can analyse. More camera trap studies are starting to use this method, so I suspect this question may eventually be relevant to quite a few people, especially when thousands of files are routinely backed up off-site prior to keywording.

I have had some students in South Africa keyword one of my camera trap surveys. These students have made errors in the past, so I need to double check their work before analysing. I have all of the photos (which I gave them) with the same filenames. I would like to know if it is possible for them to extract the keywords to a .txt file (using -filename and -keyword operators) in South Africa, email that file to me and THEN for me to write those keywords to the same files on my hard drive. This would be considerably easier than transferring 60 Gb of photographs.

I am using MacOSX 10, so perhaps this is more of an Automator problem, but many camera trap users have PCs, so it would be better to use exiftool if possible.

Answer (score 0):

David, you can export to a csv file using exiftool, something like:

```
exiftool -xmp:all -csv . > ThisSet.csv
```

Make your corrections to that csv file in a spreadsheet, then import to your images.

```
exiftool -overwrite_original_in_place -L -csv=\Users\TIPUTINI\DarwinCore\ThisSet.csv \Users\TIPUTINI\DarwinCore\Photos\
```

I was doing something similiar at a research station in the Ecuadorian Amazon.

Note that exiftool supports embedding Darwin Core into the captured images. I think that would be very useful for camera trap images, don't you?